# How do I refer to root project directory in WPF XAML when setting paths to other files?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm having issues referring to image files and other XAML files when the files are in a higher level directory then the XAML file from which I am referring to them from. Is there a way to refer to the root of the project directory?

For example I have the following files & directories:

1. Project Root Folder: \root
2. Icon in root folder: \root\AppIcon.ico
3. Subdirectory: \root\subdirectory
4. Xaml file 'window.xaml' in subdirectory: \root\subdirectory\window.xaml

How do I refer to \root\AppIcon.ico in the xaml of \root\subdirectory\window.xaml?
If I want to set the icon of window window.xaml i should put what here: icon="what do I put here"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `..\appicon.ico` to come up by one level. add as many as u need depending on the folder nesting

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you use `..\` more than one time, it will consider address as the URI and throw an exception:

> ...operation failed with URI '.. \ ..\application.ico'